# What is the best way to enumerate all the numbers between 1 to n having kth bit set?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

What is the best way to enumerate all the numbers between 1 to `n` having `kth` bit set?

For example:
 when `n = 12` and `k = 1`, answer will be `1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11`.
If `k = 2`, answer will be `2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11`.

One trivial approach is to loop over `n` and check if `kth` bit is set (by checking `num & (1 << (k-1))` is `1` or `0`) but is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

If you increment the number and there should be a carry from the part below k to the part above k, that carry will propagate across and leave the kth bit 0, otherwise it stays 1.

So all you need to do is switch the kth bit back on:

```
x = (x + 1) | (1 << k);
```

Just loop that until you've reached your upper bound, sort of like this (just an example)

```
for (int x = 1 << k; x < n; x = (x + 1) | (1 << k))
    print(x); // or whatever
```

Comment: Seems correct :) This should be better than mine +1

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that we have n bits, and bit k is fixed to 1, so those number we looking for will look like `xxxx1xxxx`, so we only need to generate all numbers with (n - 1) bits.

For example, if we have 3 bits, and we want bit 2 is set, so we only need to generate 2^(n - 1) = 4 numbers, and the final numbers look like : x1x

so  these numbers are 0(00) , 1(01) , 2(10), 3(11) -> add in bit 2, the final number we look for is 2(010), 3(011), 6(110), 7(111)

Pseudo code:

```
   int n = ...//User input
   int bit = numberOfBitUsed(n)
   for(int i = 0; i < (1<<bit); i++){
       int number = generateNumber(i, k);
       if(number > n){
          break;
       }

   }
```

**Note**: with some bit manipulations, we can implement `generateNumber(int number, int k)` with O(1) time complexity

```
 int generateNumber(int val, int k){
    int half = Integer.MAX_VALUE & ~((1<<k) - 1);//Mask for bit from 31 to k 
    int a = half & val;
    a <<=1;
    int b = ((1<<k) - 1) & val;
    int num = a | b | (1<<k);
    return num;
 }
```

Comment: you cut the work in half because you removed one bit. and added some extra overhead. not sure if this is actually faster.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath You could be right!, however, we can generate the number in O(1) (as in my updated answer) so, there is a chance of improvement :)